# Push notifcation - land on the same page after clicking on it

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push

We have an application which handles push notification for both Android and iOs.
Now when the user receives a push notification, the user get redirected to the home page application.

Is it possible for a particular push message, to get redirected to another page of the app (always the same) and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should look at each platforms, Apple's and Google's, documentation with regards to deep linking and then implement your application appropriately.  Your application handles URLs sent down in push notifications, not the SDKs. (ref. https://bit.ly/2P93Pmy)